# pdf show in simulator but not in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf

I am struggling with the problem from last few hour. I make a pdf programmatically and save it on ~/library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/...  and the programs work fine for me in simulator. I can save and retrieve the pdf in webView.

But when I test my App in iPhone4 device I not see the pdf file when I retrieve. I am new so I don't know check manually that pdf created in device or not.

Please provide me help.

thanks

I save the pdf from this code :

```
- (void)generatePdfButtonPressed{

pageSize = CGSizeMake(612, 792);
NSString *fileName = @"Demo.pdf";
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

[self generatePdfWithFilePath:pdfFileName];
}


- (void) generatePdfWithFilePath: (NSString *)thefilePath
{
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(thefilePath, CGRectZero, nil);

NSInteger currentPage = 0;
BOOL done = NO;
do
{
    // Mark the beginning of a new page.
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);

    // Draw a page number at the bottom of each page.
    currentPage++;
    //[self drawPageNumber:currentPage];

    //Draw a border for each page.
  //  [self drawBorder];

    //Draw text fo our header.
    [self drawHeader];

    //Draw a line below the header.
    [self drawLine];


    //Draw personel details
    [self drawPersonelDetail];

    //Draw Education
    [self drawEducation];




    //Draw work Experiences
    [self drawWorkExperiences];

    //Draw work Activities
    [self drawActivities];


    //Draw Skills
    [self drawSkils];


    //Draw some text for the page.
 //   [self drawText];

    yCord=550;
//    [self drawText];

    //Draw an image
//    [self drawImage];
    done = YES;
}
while (!done);

// Close the PDF context and write the contents out.
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
}
```

Comment: Add log messages everywhere, and check and log return codes. Obviously something you are doing on the phone is not working and this is how you can find that place. Also, I'm not sure if "Application Support" pre-exists in the app on your phone - you may need to create it programmatically (as I said, I don't know for sure)

Comment: @DavidH thanks for reply. I wants to know. I am doing right coding for storing pdf in my device? (it works fine in simulator)

Comment: Also, you're not showing is how you store the file path that you've generated, and how you're trying to load the PDF into the web view.

Comment: If you want help, do as I suggested, then post the step that failed, you will get help then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long struggling I find the solution of my own question : I provide solution below may be it help any other.

```
- (void)generatePdfButtonPressed{

pageSize = CGSizeMake(612, 792);
NSString *fileName = @"Demo.pdf";
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

[self generatePdfWithFilePath:pdfFileName];
}


- (void) generatePdfWithFilePath: (NSString *)thefilePath
{
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(thefilePath, CGRectZero, nil);

NSInteger currentPage = 0;
BOOL done = NO;
do
{
// Mark the beginning of a new page.
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);

// Draw a page number at the bottom of each page.
currentPage++;
[self drawPageNumber:currentPage];

//Draw a border for each page.
 [self drawBorder];

//Draw text  our header.
[self drawHeader];

//Draw a line below the header.
[self drawLine];


//Draw personel details
[self drawPersonelDetail];

//Draw Education
[self drawEducation];


//Draw an image
[self drawImage];

done = YES;
}
while (!done);

// Close the PDF context and write the contents out.
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
}



And for Display the pdf file the method is :

- (void)showPdfClicked
{

pdf1View.scalesPageToFit = YES;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"%@",documentsDirectory);

NSString *path1 =[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Demo.pdf"];

NSLog(@"Retruve Save path is %@: ",path1);
// NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pdf1" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path1];
NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL1];
[pdf1View loadRequest:request1];

}
```

Comment: So, what's different between this code and your original? What solved your problem?

Comment: @SixtenOtto I am doing silly mistake before, When I create PDF I give name "Demo.pdf" but when I access the pdf file I used "demo.pdf", so it is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem before. My guess is it's a memory issue--how large is the PDF file you're trying to load? `UIWebView` seems to have have some issues buffering (if it does this at all) large files for display.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully send my created pdf by email through this code. May Be this helps you(dottorfeelgood).

```
-(IBAction)emailButtonClicked
{


MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[picker setSubject:@"Subject"];


NSString *fileName = @"Demo.pdf";
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];



NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];


pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfFileName];

CGRect bounds=CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792);
[picker addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"SomeFile.pdf"];




// Fill out the email body text
NSString *emailBody = @"Image is attached";
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

//[picker release];


}
```

Happy Coding!!!